# GNUPlot : Can't set ylabel vertical

Tags: label, latex, gnuplot

Good Morning,

I'm using `GNUPlot` with `LaTeX` term to import graphics in `LaTeX`.
By default my y-label is horizontal and I want it to be vertical.

Writing the following does give the results I'm after:

```
set term latex 
set out 'm16.tex'

set xrange [0:20] 
set datafile separator ',' 
set key inside bottom 
set size 0.65,0.9 
set xlabel 'Number of samples'
set ylabel 'Occurences' rotate by 90
```

Comment: You're missing a `set` in front of `ylabel`, but assuming that is not the problem, can you post your code so people can try to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I have the "set".
I'm going to edit le post. Without the "rotate by 90" it is horizontal

Comment: I'm not sure about the maintenance state of the `latex` terminal. The `cairolatex` and `epslatex` terminals work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `rotate` option when setting the latex terminal:

```
set term latex rotate
```

From `help latex`:

> If 'rotate' is specified, rotated text, especially a rotated y-axis label,
>    is possible (the packages graphics or graphicx are needed). The 'stacked'
>    y-axis label mechanism is then deactivated.